# How to run a program from a server on a file stored on a local machine

Tags: ssh

I have a C file stored on my machine that I wish to execute using a program on an external server. The reason that for doing this is space requirements - I don't have storage space on the external server but I do have space on my local machine. Can I still avail of the benefits of the external server if I use it to run a program on my local machine?

For example, I run the current code using "mpirun -np 16 ./c.x" but that is while I am logged into the server and c.x sits on a machine that the server can access. Is there a way of running "mpirun" using "ssh"?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What are the program's inputs and outputs? Where are the inputs currently located? An example would probably help a lot.

Comment: can mpirun take the file contents from STDIN? otherwise if it needs to read the file from disk and given your storage restrictions I thinks is not posible.

Comment: I can research that @Dalvenjia. I CAN have it such that the file is read from disk. The output file is very large, however, and I would then need it to be transferred to the local machine IF it has been created in a folder that the remote server can access.

Comment: Other option is to make your local machina an NFS server sharing a directory where you would put your large file, then you can mount your shared folder on the remote machine and access the file as it were local. Take in consideration your network setup and the permissions on both servers (you need root to set up NFS locally and also to mount remotely). I'm assuming this is all in a local network, if you are using the internet there are other security implications.

Comment: Does the output file have a fixed name, or can you change the name or supply the name as a parameter on the command line when you run your program?

Comment: @Mark: the output file has a fixed name.

Comment: Maybe someone can flesh this out, as I'm on a mobile right now. On the remote, and this can all be on a single command line that you give to ssh, create a named pipe with the same name as the output file, start an scp in the background to copy the file to your local system, and then start the mpirun program.

Comment: Why not just export the directory containing the data over nfs / smb and mont it where the program resides or, if the remote system is linux, use sshfs http://blog.damontimm.com/how-to-mount-a-sftp-folder-ssh-ftp-on-ubuntu-linux-using-sshfs-fuse/

Answer (score 1):

### When your command is on the local system, and your file argument is on the remote...

Use *[process substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html)*.

**In Bash**

```
mpirun -np 16 <(ssh server cat c.x)
```

The `<(command)` syntax allows you to convert output from a shell command into a file, basically.

**In Zsh**

```
mpirun -np 16 =(ssh server cat c.x)
```

---

### When your file is on the local system and you want to run the command on the remote...

```
ssh remote "mpirun -np 16 /dev/fd/0" < c.x
```

This may or may not work depending on the needs of the mpirun program.

Comment: Thanks @Raymond for your response. So this process substitution command is run on the local machine? If so, is the "mpirun" command piped to the server.....executed there.....and finally the output file is stored on the local machine?

Comment: This is for the situation where the mpirun command is on the local server and c.x is on the remote.  It was difficult to tell from your question and example which was where.  Do you mean to say that your interactive shell is on the local server and your program file c.x is on the remote?

Comment: Well it can be set up like you explain. My original suggested setup was that the interactive shell and program file are on the local server. My requirement is that I would like to avail of the faster processing on the remote server as well as the limitless space on my local machine.